# Binding Dynamic Values With Google's Dynamic Outlined Text With Icon

Tags: formula-field, google, text

We all know standard salesforce doesn't allow colored texts. If we want to go with colored text we must create visualforce page. But if we use google charts api's dynamic outlined text format in formula field of salesforce then we can achieve colored text in salesforce.

Reference : [Google dynamic outlined texts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#outlined-font-text-blocks-no--icon)

Reference : [Google dynamic outlined texts with icon](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#outlined--font-text-blocks-icon)

`My question` : I want to bind account.name with string value in formula field. **We can bind value with Google dynamic outlined text**. For ex, I used this formula in formula field with bind value Account.Name.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Type , "other"), IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=FF0000|20|l|ffffff|_|"+"This is case type other "+ Account.Name , "") , "")
```

output : [image]

**Can we bind Account.Name with Google dynamic outlined texts with icon?**
I used below formula in formula field,

```
If(ISPICKVAL(Type, "Other"), IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_simple_text_icon_left&chld=This+case+type+is+other|18|FF0000|caution|24|FF0000|ffffff|", ""), "")
```

Output : [image]

**Can we Bind Account.Name with those texts in Google dynamic outline texts  with icon?**

Thoughts,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_simple_text_icon_left&chld= |18|FF0000|caution|24|FF0000|ffffff|", "") & " " & IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=FF0000|20|l|ffffff|_|"+"This is case type other "+Name , "")
```